# creating a more complex sudoku (69x6)

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, problem-solving

I would like to know if its possible to create a "sodoku" with this rule: in a table $69\times 6$ i want to put in the numbers from $1$ to $46$ repeated $9$ times, each numbers HAS to stay in the same column with every other number $1$ and only $1$ time.

Meaning: if I have the $9$ columns that have the number $1$ in it, the other $5\times 9$ $(45)$ numbers will be all the numbers from $2$ to $46$ so that $1$ is with all numbers $1$ and only $1$ time.

(i made a program that tries to fill in the numbers but i was never able to put in more than $382$ of $414$ numbers) here it is: http://pastebin.com/JFtb8SVg

i didn't post it here because its $350$ lines, and commented in Italian, i don't so much want you to correct my program as much as tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

Thanks

Gokalex

Comment: A table $69 \times 6$ means 69 rows and 6 columns.  I cannot reconcile these dimensions with your description of "9 columns that have the number 1 in it".

Comment: @hardmath i have a table that is 69 columns and 6 rows, not the other way around, what i mean by "9 columns that have the number 1 in it" is that lets say that the 1st 9 of the 69 columns contain the number 1 somehwere, the other 45 cells that are above or below the number 1 (in those 9 columns) have to have all the other numbers from 2 to 46 ( 5 free slots for 9 clums, 45 free cells)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for a $(46,6,1)$ [block design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design#Definition_of_a_BIBD_.28or_2-design.29). According to [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1520-6610%282001%299:1%3C60%3a%3aAID-JCD5%3E3.0.CO;2-W/abstract) they don't exist.

---

A few notes to help with reading the links. Wikipedia says:

> a family of $k$-element subsets of $X$, called blocks, such that the number $r$ of blocks containing $x$ in $X$ is not dependent on which $x$ is chosen, and the number $\lambda$
>    of blocks containing given distinct points $x$ and $y$ in $X$ is also
>   independent of the choices.

In your case, the set $X$ is the set of integers $\{ 1,2,\ldots, 46 \}$. The size of $X$ is called $v$, so $v=46$. The blocks are the columns, each of which has size $k=6$. The number of blocks containing an integer $x \in X$ is independent of $X$: namely, that number is $9$. Given distinct integers $x$ and $y$ in $X$, the number of blocks containing $x$ and $y$ is independent of the particular values of $x$ and $y$: namely, that number is $\lambda=1$.

Scrolling down, I read "The design is called a $(v, k, \lambda)$-design." So I googled for `(46,6,1) block design`.

Scanning through the early pages of the paper, I see the following on the second page:

> The incidence matrix of such a design has 46 rows and 69 columns. In each row, there are 9 ones. In each column, there are 6 ones. Each pair of rows intersect in exactly one column.

So this is your construction. Instead of writing $6$ numbers in a columns, they write a column of height $46$ with $6$ ones in it.

The rest of the paper explained that this is the result of an 80,000 hour computation (presumably done in parallel, since that is 9 years), so I stopped reading.

Comment: im not sure if what im trying to make is a (46,6,1) block design, im not sure what block designs are, (trying to understand that from the wiki but im not sure if its the same thing)

Comment: Does the edit help?

Comment: correct me if im wrong, with the notation (46,6,1) the 46 is the number of integers im trying to insert in my table, 6 is the size of each column (or the number of rows) and 1 is the number if times each numbers has to stay in the same column with every other number, correct? if (46,6,1) is impossible would (46,9,1) be possible (so creating a table 46x9 instead of 69x6) (i googled it but found no answer for "(46,9,1) block design")

Comment: $(46,9,1)$ can't occur. For each integer $x$ other than $1$, we are supposed to have $x$ and $1$ occur together exactly once. But each column contains $9$ elements, so each column that contains $1$ puts $8$ numbers together with $1$, and $8$ does not divide $45$.

Comment: +1 Nice find!  The existence of such a balanced incomplete block design (BIBD) was listed as unknown by Fischer and Yates in 1943, tabulating all the feasible designs with element repetitions $r \le 10$ and whether they had been constructed (here $r=9$).  See the historical discussion in the second paragraph of [this 1973 paper](http://www.uow.edu.au/~jennie/WEBPDF/032_1973.pdf).

Comment: @hardmath thankyou very much for your article, now i know what tables i can try to make (not impossible), would you by any chance know how to extract the design using those codes? (im googling for a solution but still havent found one)

Comment: My go-to site for such things is the [La Jolla Covering Repository](http://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html), which provides the blocks for somewhat more general combinatorial designs.  Your case is a $2-(46,6,1)$ Steiner system, meaning that we ask each pair ($t=2$) of elements to appear exactly once (where covering designs relax this to appearing at least once) in any block.  While no Steiner system for your parameters exists, there is a best covering design known with 73 blocks (use the search widget to look it up on their landing page) found by Anastasios Tampakis.